# Como saber se uma requisição Json não retornou resultado?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

Tenho um código em `JavaScript` que faz uma busca em um banco de dados e preenche um `input` com o nome do paciente encontrado:

```
$("#bCns").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var options = {};
        options.url = "/Home/pegaPaciente";
        options.type = "GET";
        options.data = { "pCns": $("#bCns").val() };
        options.dataType = "json";
        options.success = function (data) {
            $("#pnPaciente").css("display", "block");
            $("#bNome").val(data.nome); //<<PREENCHE AQUI
        };
        $.ajax(options);
    }
});
```

Quero saber como fazer um `if` para, caso não tenha nenhum resultado, ele preencha `$("#bNome").val("PACIENTE NAO ENCONTRADO");`

No meu `Controller` faço a consulta no banco assim:

```
public JsonResult pegaPaciente(string pCns)
{
paciente oPaciente = modelOff.pacientes.SingleOrDefault(p => p.cns == pCns);
return Json(oPaciente, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Já tentei:

```
if (!data){}
if (data == false){}
```

Comment: Isso depende do que o banco de dados devolve se não houver nenhum paciente encontrado.

Comment: Alterei a pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazendo uma alteração no `Controller`:

```
public JsonResult pegaPaciente(string pCns)
{
    paciente oPaciente = modelOff.pacientes.SingleOrDefault(p => p.cns == pCns);
    if (oPaciente == null)
        return Json("nao", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    else
        return Json(oPaciente, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

E o `.js` ficou assim:

```
$("#bCns").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var options = {};
        options.url = "/Home/pegaPaciente";
        options.type = "GET";
        options.data = { "pCns": $("#bCns").val() };
        options.dataType = "json";
        options.success = function (data) {
        if (data == "nao"){
            alert("nada aqui");
            }
            else{
            $("#pnPaciente").css("display", "block");
            $("#bNome").val(data.nome); //<<PREENCHE AQUI
            }};
        $.ajax(options);
    }
});
```